# Formula to insert and update queue number based on priority rating

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to create a formula which assigns a number to a row of data.

The factors to include are

1. Data is a list of people on a waiting list
2. The data to reference is a priority level of 1, 2 or 3
3. I want the formula to check the priority level, and then assign the next available queue number based on that priority, but moving everyone else below it
4. 

i.e.

```
Person A - Priority 1 - Queue Position 1
Person B - Priority 2 - Queue Position 2
```

then Person C comes along, Priority 1, I want a formula or perhaps it has to be VBA? to do this

```
Person A - Priority 1 - Queue Position 1
Person C - Priority 1 - Queue Position 2
Person B - Priority 2 - Queue Position 3
```

I have searched and searched but struggling to find the right formula or search terms to get me started. Any pointers would be much appreciated

I have tried to use IFS function/formula
I have searched for VBA code

I am using VBA code and many other formulas to do different functions in the workbook

Comment: One way, is to create a Unique ID for each person starting from 1 and upwards, then sort your data by Priority and Unique ID, this will give you the correct order, to automate the position number you could use the following formula `=IF(ROW()=2,1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))+1)`  2 being the first person row, change this row number as required.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula to sort the list:

```vb
=LET(d,tblData,
s,SORTBY(INDEX(d,,1),INDEX(d,,2),1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)),1),
q,SEQUENCE(ROWS(s),1),
HSTACK(s,q))
```

`SortBy` sorts by priority **and** by position on the list.
Assumption is that you enter each new person at the end of the list.

[image]